# Robolectric 3 Resource Not Found Error

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, robolectric

I am trying to incorporate Robolectric 3 into my project but I seem to be having more issues than I anticipated. At the moment, I am trying to instantiate a simple activity in my test class's setUp method via

```
MyActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MyActivity.class);
```

I have placed the following at the top of my test file:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
```

In MyActivity I simply access a string array resource via:

```
getResources().getStringArray(resId)
```

After I run the test class (without any test methods, only the setUp method which instantiates the activity), I get the error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String array resource ID #0x7f0c0000
at android.content.res.Resources.getStringArray(Resources.java:502)
at com.alivemobile.tpff.slidingtabs.views.SlidingTabsActivity$3.onItemSelected(SlidingTabsActivity.java:102)
at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:897)
at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:865)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOrQueueRunnable(Scheduler.java:230)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.postDelayed(Scheduler.java:85)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.post(Scheduler.java:72)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowView.post(ShadowView.java:401)
at android.view.View.post(View.java)
at android.widget.AdapterView.selectionChanged(AdapterView.java:882)
at android.widget.AdapterView.checkSelectionChanged(AdapterView.java:1047)
at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:586)
at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:527)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.layoutChildLeft(Toolbar.java:1565)
at android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onLayout(Toolbar.java:1504)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1703)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1557)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1466)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15596)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4966)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2072)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1829)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.dispatchMessage(ShadowMessageQueue.java:130)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue.access$100(ShadowMessageQueue.java:30)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowMessageQueue$1.run(ShadowMessageQueue.java:95)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(Scheduler.java:269)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.runOneTask(Scheduler.java:179)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceTo(Scheduler.java:160)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.advanceBy(Scheduler.java:143)
at org.robolectric.util.Scheduler.unPause(Scheduler.java:54)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.unPause(ShadowLooper.java:266)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:306)
at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.visible(ActivityController.java:173)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.setup(ActivityController.java:210)
at org.robolectric.Robolectric.setupActivity(Robolectric.java:46)
at com.alivemobile.tpff.events.views.list.EventsListTests.setUp(EventsListTests.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:251)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:188)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:152)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I have googled around and saw a few people implementing a custom test runner, and I had tried some, but they all seem overly complicated without much explanation as to what is going on.
What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE 1**
After playing around a little, I discovered that if I instantiate the activity in my setUp() method with:

```
Robolectric.buildActivity(SlidingTabsActivity.class).create().start().resume().get();
```

rather than:

```
Robolectric.setupActivity(SlidingTabsActivity.class);
```

The test does not give a Resource Not Found Error.

However if I instatiate the activity with:

```
Robolectric.buildActivity(SlidingTabsActivity.class).create().start().resume().visible().get();
```

*then* I get the Resource Not Found Error.

Comment: `@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)`,you are missing `sdk = 21`. Show us your entire test.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem, I have already specified a maximum sdk version of 21 in my app's build.gradle file. The entire test is quite literally:
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)

and a setUp method instantiating the activity (I have tried a number of ways as mentioned in the OP)

Comment: You need to post more. Is this for an app? Is this for a library? what Is in your test? What is in your MainActivity?

Answer (score 1):

We had similar problem in tests using robolectric. It was because we have different build flavors which have different applicationId from our package structure. 
RobolectricGradleTestRunner class by default picks the resources, assets and manifest from your src/main folder. So you don't need to implement a custom test runner.
Check if the applicationId in your gradle build is different from the package structure. Your applicationId may be com.something.abc and your base package maybe com.something.xyz
If you are using different build flavors and applicationId for each build flavors then I suggest to add following to your test suite.

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, packageName = "com.something.xyz")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My applicationId seems to be fine (it is the same as the package name in my src/main folder). However I just discovered something interesting. I have updated the OP to reflect my findings.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `CustomRobolectricTestRunner`like this.

```
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

public class CustomRobolectricTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {
public CustomRobolectricTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
    super(testClass);
}

@Override
protected Config buildGlobalConfig() {
    return Config.Builder.defaults()
            .setPackageName("com.x")
            .setManifest("build/intermediates/manifest/androidTest/debug/AndroidManifest.xml")
            .setResourceDir("../../../../res/merged/androidTest/debug") // relative to manifest
            .build();
}
}
```

Here path for the manifest file and resource directory should be correct. So you can check correct path for it in `build/intermediates` directoryof your project.

Note: Resource directory path needs to be relative to manifest path.

In your test class, you need to use `CustomRobolectricTestRunner` like this.

```
@org.junit.runner.RunWith(CustomRobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyTestClass {
}
```

Comment: It works! althought a bit better would be to use "src/test/AndroidManifest.xml" for manifest and "../main/res" for resource

Answer (score 0):

We have default package for all resource and this custom TestRunner helps us.

```js
public class RobolectricGradleTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    public RobolectricGradleTestRunner(final Class<?> testClass) throws InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(final Config config) {
        final String myAppPath = RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        final String manifestPath = myAppPath + "../../../../manifests/full/" + BuildConfig.FLAVOR + "/" + BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE + "/AndroidManifest.xml";
        final String resPath = myAppPath + "../../../../res/merged/" + BuildConfig.FLAVOR + "/" + BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE;
        final String assetPath = myAppPath + "../../../../assets/" + BuildConfig.FLAVOR + "/" + BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE;

        return new AndroidManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(manifestPath),
                Fs.fileFromPath(resPath),
                Fs.fileFromPath(assetPath),
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID) {

            @Override
            public String getRClassName() throws Exception {
                return "[your_package_name].R";
            }

        };
    }
}
```